# Aceptar cualquier caracter menos $%&|<># con RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Soy algo nuevo en programación web y con *Expresiones Regulares (RegEX)*. ¿Cómo permitir que mi *TextArea* acepte cualquier caracter excepto  estos `$%&|<>#`?

Estoy probando esto con mi **TMForm.js**.

```
regula.custom({
    name:'Special' 
    ,validator:function(){
        return /^[A-Za-z ]-[$%&|<>#]?$/.test(this.value)
    }
})
```

Este es mi textarea en mi archivo php.

```
<label class="message">
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="cf_message" placeholder="Insert your message:" data-constraints="@Required @Special"> 
       </textarea>
    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
    <span class="error-message">*Must have at least 5 characters.</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Jorge, éste es StackOverflow en Español, no en Inglés, por lo tanto, tus preguntas deben estar en español (aunque muchos entiendan, lo que es irrelevante).

Comment: Perdon, mi pregunta basicamente es como puedo hacer para que mi textarea lea cualquier caracter menos $%&|<>#.

Comment: Jorge, puedes editar tu pregunta y dejarlo en Español

Comment: Ya esta editado. Perdon por los inconvenientes.

Comment: Por si de algo ayuda... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La siguiente expresión regular coincidirá con cualquier texto que contenga los caracteres `$%&|<>#`.

```
/[$%&|<>#]/
```

- `[]`: agrupa una serie de caracteres (que coincidirán)

Nota: gracias a @Mariano por notar que el `/g` está de más porque solo basta la primera coincidencia.

```js
function validate (e) {
  // valores inválidos
  if(/[$%&|<>#]/.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.classList.remove('valid');
    e.target.classList.add('invalid');
  } else {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
    e.target.classList.add('valid');
  }
}
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #d53400;
}
.valid {
  border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="validate(event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente RegExp:

```
/^[^$%&|<>#]*$/
```

Descripción:

```
/^                 : Empieza con
 [^                : Que no sea uno de los caracteres
   $%&|<>#         : Caracteres a excluir
 ]
 *                 : 0 o mas caracteres
$/                 : Termina en
```

Demo:

```js
var re = /^[^$%&|<>#]*$/;

document.getElementById('message')
  .addEventListener('input', function () {
    console.log(this.value + ': '+ re.test(this.value));
    this.className = re.test(this.value) ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
  });
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  background-color: #0c0;
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Insert your message:"></textarea>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron. Las soluciones me sirvieron para mejorar el codigo y aprender mejor acerca de los RegEx

Answer (score 0):

message:" data-constraints="@Required @Special"

todas las restricciones y condiciones especiales de tu formulario deberian ir en el js o en un php a parte, no en el documento html porque son suceptibles a ser modificados, cualquiera que sepa d elas herramientas de desarrollador podría saltarse alguna validacion solo borrando el elemento o el atributo